# How to run only one unit test class using Gradle?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, gradle

I am new to Gradle. I use Gradle 1.10 and Ubuntu 13.

I want to know if there's any command to execute only one unit test class, similar to [`testOnly`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Testing.html#testOnly) in SBT.

Comment: Given the answers, it should be clear this is about *local* tests, not *instrumented* tests. Android / Gradle makes things confusing by calling these local tests "unit" tests.

Comment: Switched wording from "local test" to "unit test", since "local test" seems to be an Android-specific concept, but this question is much more general than that.

Answer (score 936, accepted):

To run a single test class Airborn's answer is good.

With using some command line options, which found [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering), you can simply do something like this.

```groovy
gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest.someSpecificFeature
gradle test --tests '*SomeTest.someSpecificFeature'
gradle test --tests '*SomeSpecificTest'
gradle test --tests 'all.in.specific.package*'
gradle test --tests '*IntegTest'
gradle test --tests '*IntegTest*ui*'
gradle test --tests '*IntegTest.singleMethod'
gradle someTestTask --tests '*UiTest' someOtherTestTask --tests '*WebTest*ui'
```

From version 1.10 of gradle it supports selecting tests, using a [test filter](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/testing/TestFilter.html). For example,

```
apply plugin: 'java'

test {
  filter {
    //specific test method
      includeTestsMatching "org.gradle.SomeTest.someSpecificFeature"

     //specific test method, use wildcard for packages
     includeTestsMatching "*SomeTest.someSpecificFeature"

     //specific test class
     includeTestsMatching "org.gradle.SomeTest"

     //specific test class, wildcard for packages
     includeTestsMatching "*.SomeTest"

     //all classes in package, recursively
     includeTestsMatching "com.gradle.tooling.*"

     //all integration tests, by naming convention
      includeTestsMatching "*IntegTest"

     //only ui tests from integration tests, by some naming convention
     includeTestsMatching "*IntegTest*ui"
   }
}
```

For multi-flavor environments (a common use-case for Android), [check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51629622/2102748), as the `--tests` argument will be unsupported and you'll get an error.

Comment: the filter approach could likely also be combined with Task rules for some convenient test selection

Comment: For large test suites, even if using `--tests` to call a single test method within the class, then we see iteration over all classes even all those not being run, which is too slow.  Don't know if that slowness is due to our env or if it would impact others.  Can update if finding more.

Comment: if you need to test a nested class `gradle test --tests org.gradle.SomeTest$NestedClassTest`

Comment: The `singleMethod` one doesn't work for me (anymore?).

Answer (score 220):

In versions of Gradle prior to 5, the `test.single` system property can be used to specify a single test.

You can do `gradle -Dtest.single=ClassUnderTestTest test` if you want to test single class or use regexp like `gradle -Dtest.single=ClassName*Test test` you can find more examples of filtering classes for tests [under this link](https://docs.gradle.org/4.6/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering).

Gradle 5 removed this option, as it was superseded by [test filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#test_filtering) using the `--tests` command line option.

Answer (score 175):

In case you have a multi-module project :

let us say your module structure is

```
root-module
 -> a-module
 -> b-module
```

and the test(testToRun) you are looking to run is in b-module, with full path : com.xyz.b.module.TestClass.testToRun

As here you are interested to run the test in b-module, so you should see the tasks available for b-module.

```
./gradlew :b-module:tasks
```

The above command will list all tasks in b-module with description. 
And in ideal case, you will have a task named **test** to run the unit tests in that module.

```
./gradlew :b-module:test
```

Now, you have reached the point for running all the tests in b-module, finally you can pass a parameter to the above task to run tests which matches the certain path pattern

```
./gradlew :b-module:test --tests "com.xyz.b.module.TestClass.testToRun"
```

Now, instead of this if you run

`./gradlew test --tests "com.xyz.b.module.TestClass.testToRun"`

It will run the test task for both module a and b, which might result in failure as there is nothing matching the above pattern in a-module.

Comment: Or simply `./gradlew :b-module:test --tests testToRun`

Comment: Is there a way to determine the module in question by its underlying test? I'd like to rerun tests that only fail on our Jenkins. But I also don't get the module information from Jenkins.

Answer (score 63):

Please note that `--tests` option may not work if you have different build `types/flavors` (fails with `Unknown command-line option '--tests'`). In this case, it's necessary to specify the particular test task (e.g. `testProdReleaseUnitTest` instead of just `test`)

Comment: Can you elaborate a full example? I'm trying to run 3 tests that match a wildcard using `./gradlew test --tests *testMyCollectionTake*` and I can't tell how should I replace `test` with the wildcarded test name

Comment: Also note that the `test` task has to be used specifically; the `check` task cannot be used, for instance.

Comment: @DanielCuadra try `./gradlew testDebug --tests "*testMyCollectionTake*"`

Answer (score 53):

After much figuring out, the following worked for me:

`gradle test --tests "a.b.c.MyTestFile.mySingleTest"`

Comment: this command is not working for me. >
Error: Unknown command-line option '--tests'

Comment: This is awesome. Easy and convenient to execute specific testcase file

Comment: @Tarkik - I think the --tests has to follow _immediately_ after 'test'. I got the same...

Answer (score 19):

For multi modules projects it's necessary to use module's name and buildType:

```
./gradlew :module_name:testDebugUnitTest --tests com.package_name.TestsClass.*
```

To run some test method the same command, but with test's name:

```
./gradlew :module_name:testDebugUnitTest --tests com.package_name.TestsClass.test
```

Comment: Strange, the method name used to work but doesn't anymore. I moved from Gradle 4.8.1 to 6.9.

Answer (score 8):

Below is the command to run a single test class using `gradlew` command line option:

```
gradlew.bat Connected**your bundleVariant**AndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.TestClass
```

Below example to run class `com.example.TestClass` with variant `Variant_1`:

```
gradlew.bat ConnectedVariant_1AndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.class=com.example.TestClass
```

Answer (score 8):

Run a single test called MyTest:

```
./gradlew app:testDebug --tests=com.example.MyTest
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try to add asteriks (*) to the end.

> gradle test --tests "com.a.b.c.*"

Answer (score 0):

In my case, my eclipse java compiler warnings were set too high, and eclipse was not recognizing my class as valid for execution. Updating my compiler settings fixed the problem. You can read more about it here: [annotation-nonnull-cannot-be-resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33785727/the-type-org-eclipse-jdt-annotation-nonnull-cannot-be-resolved-it-is-indirectly)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

- Release case:

  gradle testReleaseUnitTest --tests testClass
- Debug case:

  gradle testDebugUnitTest --tests AsyncExecutorTest

You can see de projects with: `gradle -q projects` and move to the project where is the class to test

Answer (score 0):

This is for Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.**kts**) tested with Gradle 8.2:

```kotlin
tasks.test {
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching("*Util*")
    }
}
```

Another way (creating a new task):

```
tasks.register<Test>("MyTests") {
    group = "MyCustomTasks"
    filter {
        includeTestsMatching("ir.mahozad.*Convert*")
    }
}
```