# Does Robolectric have an annotation similar to Mocha's .only()

Tags: android, unit-testing, gradle, robolectric

I'd like to run only 1 test in 1 file. Identical to adding .only() to a Mocha test. Is there an annotation that I can add to a test so only that test is run?

Comment: Do you mean you want to disable all tests (except one) on CI or you want to run one test in AndroidStudio?

Comment: I just want to run one unit test.

Comment: In AS or from command line?

Comment: I've tried this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-a-one-test-class-only-on-gradle but it didn't work. Looks like test classes are compiled to another folder. So it is most probably doable. I'm adding gradle tag to involve build tool community