# Minimum code coverage threshold in Jacoco Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy, jacoco

How can I set the minimum code coverage in [Jacoco Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html)?

I want the build to fail if it is not met.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The feature is now available. You simply need to apply the Gradle JaCoCo plugin and define coverage verification like this:

```
apply plugin: 'jacoco'

jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.7
            }
        }
    }
}

// to run coverage verification during the build (and fail when appropriate)
check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

The last line is very important as your build would otherwise not fail unless you explicitly run the `jacocoTestCoverageVerification` task.

More information on the kind of checks you may add is in the [documentation of the plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html#sec:jacoco_report_violation_rules).

Comment: I've lost 1h before realizing you need `check.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification` :|

Answer (score 6):

In an Android application this configuration works:

**project**: build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4"
        classpath "org.jacoco:org.jacoco.core:0.8.2"
    }
}
```

**app**: build.gradle

```
ext.jacoco_version = '0.8.2'
def configDir = "${project.rootDir}/config"
def reportDir = "${project.buildDir}/reports"
def mainSrc = "$project.projectDir/src/main/java"
def fileFilter = ['**/R.class', '**/R$*.class', '**/BuildConfig.*', '**/Manifest*.*', '**/*Test*.*', 'android/**/*.*']
def debugTree = fileTree(dir: "$project.buildDir/intermediates/classes/debug", excludes: fileFilter)
//Jacoco jacocoTestReport
apply plugin: 'jacoco'
jacoco.toolVersion = jacoco_version
task jacocoTestReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testDebugUnitTest') {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = false
        html.enabled = true
    }
    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = fileTree(dir: project.buildDir, includes: [
            'jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec', 'outputs/code-coverage/connected/*coverage.ec'
    ])
}
task jacocoTestCoverageVerification(type: JacocoCoverageVerification, dependsOn: 'jacocoTestReport') {
    sourceDirectories = files([mainSrc])
    classDirectories = files([debugTree])
    executionData = files("${buildDir}/jacoco/testDebugUnitTest.exec")
    violationRules {
        failOnViolation = true
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.7
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We can execute it in commandline with:

```
./gradlew jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

I used gradle wrapper 4.4.

Comment: Hi, really your explanation helped me a lot. Is there a way to test one particular class alone have the limit or not?

Comment: Yes, look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-local-test-class-on-gradle

Answer (score 3):

Gradle Jacoco Plugin by default will test **Instruction** coverage with below code:

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                minimum = 0.85
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I had the requirement to test **Line** and **Branch** Coverage. In order to mention this to Jacoco, we will have to use [Counter](https://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/trunk/doc/api/org/jacoco/core/analysis/ICoverageNode.CounterEntity.html). Counter can have various values like: INSTRUCTION, LINE, BRANCH, COMPLEXITY, METHOD and CLASS. Instruction is the default one.

In order to validate both Line and branch coverage, one can use below code:

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
    violationRules {
        rule {
            limit {
                counter = 'LINE'
                minimum = 0.87
            }
            limit {
                counter = 'BRANCH'
                minimum = 0.80
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One rule  can contain multiple Limits.

Ref: https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/testing/jacoco/tasks/rules/JacocoViolationRulesContainer.html

Answer (score 2):

This might help

Add plugins as below

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
    id 'java'
    id 'jacoco'
}
```

Add jacoco version

```
jacoco {
    toolVersion = "0.8.8"
}
```

Add jacocoTestCoverageVerification task with minimum 80% coverage

```
jacocoTestCoverageVerification {
dependsOn test
enabled = true
violationRules {
    rule {
        limit {
            minimum = 0.5
        }
    }
    rule {
        element = 'CLASS'
        excludes = [
                'com.anypackage.*',
                'com.morepackage.*'
        ]
        limit {
            counter = 'CLASS'
            minimum = 0.8
        }
    }
}
```

}

to run jacocoTestCoverageVerification on every build

```
build.dependsOn jacocoTestCoverageVerification
```

Update test task

```
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    finalizedBy jacocoTestCoverageVerification
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the compete Example

```
task wrapper(type: Wrapper){ 
     gradleVersion = '4.8' 
} 

plugins { 
    id 'java' 
    id 'maven' 
    id "jacoco" 
} 

jacoco{ 
    toolVersion = '0.8.1' 
} 

jacocoTestCoverageVerification { 
    violationRules { 
        rule { 
            limit { 
                minimum = 0.5 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 


jacocoTestReport { 
     reports { 
        csv.enabled false 
        xml.enabled false 
        html { 
            enabled true 
            destination file("$buildDir/reports/jacoco") 
        } 
    } 
   executionData(test) 
} 

tasks.build.dependsOn(jacocoTestReport) 

test{ 
    jacoco{ 
        append = false 
        destinationFile = file("$buildDir/jacoco/jacocoTest.exec") 
        classDumpDir = file("$buildDir/jacoco/classpathdumps") 
    } 
}
```