# How to execute Espresso multiple test classes separately using gradlew command

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have Espresso instrumentaion test cases in following form in Android studio.

[image: Screen from Android Studio]

Now, I want to run few of the classes separately.

E.g : I want to run Only CrashersTest and EM3AppUtil classes using gradlew command and rest classes using another command.

How can i achieve it?

- I am using below command

> ./gradlew :app:connectedLocalDebugAndroidTest

- It runs all the classes for LocalDebug variant
- I want to run only few classes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a great way to do it for **instrumented tests** right now that I know of.

You can create a test suite to run just certain test you want, like documented here
https://developer.android.com/training/testing/unit-testing/instrumented-unit-tests.html#test-suites

Or use the @SmallTest, @MediumTest or @LargeTest annotations on your tests and then pass in on command line like so

```
./gradlew connectedAndroidTest -Pandroid.testInstrumentationRunnerArguments.size=small
```

Comment: This helped me. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Place the cursor on the class name in java file or select the file in file view then press `ctrl+shift+F10`

Refer this [How to run only one test class on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22505533/2809326) for running tests from gradlew command

Comment: I see, but i dont see any way of filtering instrumentation test cases. This one is for the Junit test case.