# Generate separate coverage reports for tests using Jacoco or IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, code-coverage, jacoco

I have a Java application set up on IntelliJ IDEA. I have several tests for which I need to generate coverage reports individually for each of the tests.

IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner runs all the tests at once and generates a single report showing the overall coverage. How can I use IntelliJ IDEA coverage runner or Jacoco plugin in gradle script to generate separate reports the tests?

Comment: you can use jacoco plugin in gradle

Comment: I have tried using jacoco plugin in gradle, but its giving me a single report with the overall coverage after running all the tests. What I want is separate reports for the tests.

Comment: you can click on the row on the overall report to see detail. Each detail report is just html file which you can see under jacoco folder

Answer (score 0):

Run tests separately one by one (see [How to run only one test class on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-test-class-on-gradle)), for each run use separate directory to save report.

Comment: The link you have given is only about how to run specific tests using gradle. How do I get coverage report for that run?

Comment: The same way as for run of all tests - https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html

Comment: As I am having many tests, so instead of doing separately one by one, is there any script to automate the process?