# Run specific test using gradle in scala test module

Tags: scala, unit-testing, gradle

I have following structure for my "tests" module written in scala

```
tests/
    build.gradle
    src/
         resources/
         scala/
             system/basic/SomeTests.scala
```

I can run all tests under scala folder using

```
./gradlew tests:test
```

How can I run only SomeTests.scala from command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run only one test class on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-test-class-on-gradle)

Answer (score 1):

If it is not different to Java, then by using the `--tests` task parameter like

```
./gradlew tests:test --tests system.basic.SomeTests
```

to run all tests in that class, or e.g.

```
./gradlew tests:test --tests system.basic.SomeTests.foo
```

to only run the `foo` test method.

Comment: it still ends up running all the tests looking like --tests param is not entertained at all

Comment: Run with `-i` and / or `-d` to get more info on what is going on and add the output to your question

Comment: hmm this doesnt work for Gradle 6.9. Command: `./gradlew tests:test --tests  someProject.TestClass` gives: `Project 'tests' not found in root project 'someProject'.`

Comment: Well, it seems you do not have a project called `tests` @xhudik. OP has such a project. ;-)