# gradle test: how to run one method?

Tags: testing, gradle

How to run just one method of a test case for debugging with Gradle? I have tried:

```
gradle test -tests example.TestFoo#testMethod1 --debug-jvm
```

but it ends up with following error:

```
No tests found for given includes: example.TestFoo#testMethod1
```

The test `TestFoo` class has `testMethod1()`, `testMethod2()`, etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to run only one test class on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-test-class-on-gradle) 1st answer also includes how to run only one method.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `.` instead `#` in your tests filter expression to point to a method name:

```
gradle test --tests example.TestFoo.testMethod1 --debug-jvm
```

You can find more examples on filtering tests in [48.14.3. Test filtering](https://docs.gradle.org/4.4.1/userguide/java_plugin.html#test_filtering) documentation section.

Comment: I tried gradle 4.0, 4.2 and gradle 4.4.1 as indicated in your link. It did not work. Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [example.TestFoo.testMethod1](--tests filter). thanks.

Comment: @Sunnyday Double check if `example.TestFoo` is present in `src/test/java/example/` folder (or `src/test/groovy/example/` is you use Groovy for testing). Also check if running `gradle test -tests example.TestFoo` works - if not, then there is a problem with loading test class.

Comment: It is parameterized test. example.TestFoo.testMethod1[0] works. Thanks.

Comment: shouldn't it be --tests instead of -tests?