# How to run Karate Test on Gradle Using Command line

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew, karate

I was having a looking on the Karate documentation : 
https://github.com/intuit/karate#command-line

And have my files as follow:

Runner class:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import com.intuit.karate.junit4.Karate;
import cucumber.api.CucumberOptions;

@RunWith(Karate.class)
@CucumberOptions(features = "classpath:feature/country.feature")
public class APITest {}
```

Place this to my build.gradle:

```
test {
    // pull cucumber options into the cucumber jvm
    systemProperty "cucumber.options", System.properties.getProperty("cucumber.options")
    // pull karate options into the jvm
    systemProperty "karate.env", System.properties.getProperty("karate.env")
    // ensure tests are always run
    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

And I'm trying to run gradle like this:

```
./gradlew test -Dtest=APITest
```

But I'm getting this response:

```
Rafaels-MacBook-Pro:TestProject rafaelpaz$ ./gradlew test -Dtest=APITest
:compileJava UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes UP-TO-DATE
:compileTestJava
:processTestResources UP-TO-DATE
:testClasses
:test
```

However, I can't see if my tests passed or not. What am I doing wrong?

Gradle version : 2.14.1

Comment: are you sure you have the syntax right to run a single test: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-test-class-on-gradle

Comment: @PeterThomas Thanks again to step up to help Peter, I tried those commands before and I was able to succeed, but only with JUnit, with Karate I get errors like this: `FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':test'.
> No tests found for given includes: [org.gradle.APITest]

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.` It's something I'm doing wrong, but still didn't realised what

Comment: sorry I can't help. man please switch to maven. I'm again going to ask on twitter for help

Comment: @PeterThomas All good mate, thanks for the help anyway! I'll still run more tests! Cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://github.com/SreecharanShroff/demos/blob/master/gradle_karate_demo.zip
has a working gradle karate demo project, please change .feature file according to your requirement.
use:

gradle clean test

please let me know if you need more info

Thanks,

Sreecharan Shroff

Comment: That's what I really needed, Sreecharan! Thank you so much for the help! I accepted your answer! Cheers mate!

Comment: Hi @Sreecharan Shroff, my test run succeeded but I don't see the generated report HTML file when I use the gradle command line for running my test, Please help if you know about this.

Comment: in gradle, by default reports are generated in projectFolder/build/reports.
I tried with Karate 0.9.2, reports are generated properly.
you can try my gradle karate project from above link.
please attach your project to reproduce the issue.