# How to create a Gradle Task to run only a specific Tests in Spring

Tags: spring, unit-testing, gradle, task, gradle-task

I have a Spring Project where I wrote some Unit and Integration Tests. Now I want to create custom tasks for running all unit tests, all integration tests and one task for running both. But how can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run only one test class on gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-test-class-on-gradle)

Comment: Alternatively, you could use the `@Suite` annotation, in order to group them as desired.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest separating integration tests into separate source set. By default you already have 2 source sets, one for production code and one for tests. To create a new source set (create new directory under `src/integrationTest/java`) and add a following configuration using Junit5:

```
test {
  useJUnitPlatform()
}

sourceSets {
  integrationTest {
    java.srcDir file("src/integrationTest/java")
    resources.srcDir file("src/integrationTest/resources")
    compileClasspath += sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
    runtimeClasspath += output + compileClasspath
  }
}
```

For separate task:

```
task integrationTest(type: Test) {
  description = 'Runs the integration tests.'
  group = 'verification'
  testClassesDirs = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDirs
  classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath

  useJUnitPlatform()

  reports {
    html.enabled true
    junitXml.enabled = true
  }
}
```

Now you have 3 tasks available:

1. `gradlew test`
2. `gradlew integrationTest`
3. `gradlew check` - runs both as it depends on Test task which both extend

If you also are using jacoco and want to merge the test results then you can have following tasks:

```
task coverageMerge(type: JacocoMerge) {
  destinationFile file("${rootProject.buildDir}/jacoco/test.exec")
  executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")
}

// aggregate all coverage data at root level
if (tasks.findByName("test")) {
  tasks.findByName("test").finalizedBy coverageMerge
}

if (tasks.findByName("integrationTest")) {
  tasks.findByName("integrationTest").finalizedBy coverageMerge
}

task codeCoverageReport(type: JacocoReport) {
  executionData fileTree(project.rootDir.absolutePath).include("**/build/jacoco/*.exec")
  subprojects.each {
    if (!it.name.contains('generated')) {
      sourceSets it.sourceSets.main
    }
  }
  reports {
    xml.enabled true
    html.enabled true
    html.setDestination(new File("${buildDir}/reports/jacoco"))
    csv.enabled false
  }
}
```

To run coverage report just execute

```
gradlew codeCoverageReport
```