# How to run a single espresso test function using android studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, android-espresso, ui-testing

I added a shell script in android studio project. I'm using this command in command line

```
./gradlew testDebugUnitTest --stackTrace org.package.package.controller.StudentGoToTheFAQActivityTest
```

Note: org. Package. Package. Controller is not a real package name

Comment: Duplicate! Question is already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-unit-test-class-using-gradle

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run only one unit test class using Gradle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-unit-test-class-using-gradle)

Comment: I tried many ways but I didnt find any solution. It run from the other mac OS device. I think my system cannot compile test classes. Don't know why

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution. I just run one test class from android studio using "blue play button" and check the stack that is running and i found this command

```
/Users/$macosUsername/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell am instrument -w -m    -e debug false -e class '$packageName.StudentGoToTheFAQActivityTest#studentGoToTheFAQActivityTest' $comBundleName.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
```

$username = Macos home directory

$packageName = package name you can find it top of the test class