# Gradle: compile and run a single test

Tags: java, gradle, code-generation, openapi

I have a separate task to run the test that generates `open-api.yml` specification for my application. Here is the Gradle configuration below:

```
task generateOpenApiYml(type: Test) {
    group = 'verification'
    useJUnitPlatform {
        includeTags 'openApi'
    }
    testLogging {
        showExceptions true
        showStandardStreams = false
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events("skipped", "failed", "passed")
    }
}
```

So, I have one test with `openApi` JUnit tag. It works very well, but there is a slight thing I want to approve.

The whole idea of this test is that the result `open-api.yml` file is used to generate Java client to invoke REST endpoints. This client is used in other tests in the project.

I want to put those generated Java classes to `.gitgnore` because they are generated anyway and there is no need to index those files. The problem is that the `generateOpenApiYml` task compiles all the tests in `src/test/java` directory. Therefore, some of them use generated classes. Which leads to compiling errors.

Is it possible to tune the `generateOpenApiYml` task to make it **compile** and **run** only the single test with `openApi` JUnit tag? Then I could easily put generated Java classes to `.gitignore` and don't bother about their temporary absence, because other tests won't be compiled.

Comment: Check if this post helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22505533/how-to-run-only-one-unit-test-class-using-gradle/31468902#31468902

Comment: @vivekmore I want to **compile** and **run** a single test. Though this command only **runs** the specified test but **compiles** all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the solution. Firstly, I installed the [gradle-testsets-plugin](https://github.com/unbroken-dome/gradle-testsets-plugin).

Then I configured a separate source set like this:

```
testSets {
    generateOpenApiYml
}
```

So, `generateOpenApiYml` is the new Gradle task that looks for sources in `src/generatedOpenApiYml/java` directory.

Afterwards, we need to tune all tasks of `test` type to bind them with JUnit 5 platform.

```
tasks.withType(Test) {
    group = 'verification'
    useJUnitPlatform()
    testLogging {
        showExceptions true
        showStandardStreams = false
        showCauses true
        showStackTraces true
        exceptionFormat "full"
        events("skipped", "failed", "passed")
    }
}

generateOpenApiYml.outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
```

I put the `upToDateWhen` option for convenience to make sure the `generateOpenApiYml` task is always run on demand and never cached.

Then I have the [open-api-generator](https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/tree/master/modules/openapi-generator-gradle-plugin).

```
openApiGenerate {
    inputSpec = "$buildDir/classes/java/generateOpenApiYml/open-api.json".toString()
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated/openapi".toString()
    apiPackage = "..."
    invokerPackage = "..."
    modelPackage = "..."
    configOptions = [
            dateLibrary    : "java8",
            openApiNullable: "false",
    ]
    generatorName = 'java'
    groupId = "..."
    globalProperties = [
            modelDocs: "false"
    ]
    additionalProperties = [
            hideGenerationTimestamp: true
    ]
}

tasks.named('openApiGenerate') {
    dependsOn generateOpenApiYml
}
```

Finally, I just need to run two commands to build and run tests for my whole project.

```bash
./gradlew openApiGenerate
./gradlew build
```

The first one creates the `open-api.yml` file and generates Java client according to the provided specification. The second one runs tests and build the project normally. The tests running during the `build` phase uses classes generated by `openApiGenerate` task. Therefore, I can put them to `.gitignore` safely.

Hope this will be helpful.