# Separate integration and unit tests with Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, junit, junit5

I'm migrating an existing Maven and JUnit 5 project where the integration and unit tests are separated into different phases:

- the `*Test.java` unit tests are run on the *test* phase
- the `*IT.java` integration tests are run on the *verify* phase

How do I accomplish the same separation with Gradle? It is my understanding that Gradle's *check* task is the equivalent to Maven's *verify*.

Comment: For a reputable answer, i would cite *all of* https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_testing.html#sec:configuring_java_integration_tests

Comment: It's possible to filter the included tests in Gradle https://stackoverflow.com/a/31468902/4161471. However, it would be more idiomatic to move the different types of tests into different source sets. The [JVM Test Suite](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jvm_test_suite_plugin.html) plugin is the best way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using filters to separate the unit and integration tests and to bind the integration tests to the **check** task:

```
tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching "*Test"
            excludeTestsMatching "*IT"
        }
    }
}

def integrationTest = tasks.register("integrationTest", Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        filter {
            includeTestsMatching '*IT'
            includeTestsMatching 'IT*'
            includeTestsMatching '*ITCase'
        }
    }
}

tasks.named('check') {
    dependsOn integrationTest
}
```